# How to setstate with arrays in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I am getting an from External APi, by which i am setting State in ComponentWillMount, but it only stores the last value of array, not the whole list of array. What am i doing wrong ?

Here is my code: 
**Update, My Full Component Code**
    class PlanStatus extends Component {

```
componentWillMount() {

  const { phone, orderNo } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  this.props.fetchPlanStatus({phone, orderNo}, (snapShotValue) => {
      const fetchedPlans = snapShotValue;
      //_.map(snapShotValue.orderValidity, (val,uid) => ({uid, ...val}))
      const markedDates = fetchedPlans.orderValidity[0].deliveryDates.forEach(element => {
          this.setState((prevState) => ({ dates: [...prevState.dates, element.date], deliveryStatus: element.deliveryStatus, startingDay: [element.startingDay], endingDay: element.endingDay }));
          console.log(element.date)            
      });
      this.setState({ finalPlanStatus: fetchedPlans })
  });
  }

onPressDateHandler(day) {
this.setState({ date: day });
console.log(this.state.dates);
 }


 state = {date: "", finalPlanStatus: null, dates: [], deliveryStatus: [], 
startingDay: "", endingDay: []}
render () {
    const date = format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    return (
      <Container>
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 30, paddingLeft: 40 }}>
          <H1>Plan Status</H1>
        </View>
        {this.props.spinner && <Spinner color='blue' />}


        <View style={this.props.spinner === false ? { display:'flex', paddingTop: 20 } : { display:'none', paddingTop: 20 }}>
           <Calendar 
           minDate={date}
           maxDate={'2019-02-20'}
           onDayPress={(day) => this.onPressDateHandler(day)}
           markedDates={
            {'2019-02-02': {color:'#22a6b3', startingDay: true, selected: true},
             '2019-02-03': {color: '#22a6b3'},
             '2019-02-05': {endingDay: true, color: '#22a6b3', textColor: 'gray'},
             '2019-02-04': {color: '#22a6b3', selected: true}
            }}
            displayLoadingIndicator
            markingType={'period'}
           />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.date.dateString}</Text>
        </View>

      </Container>
    );
}
```

}

By this, while doing forEach on deliveryDates, it correctly shows the list of array as follows:

```
deliveryDates: Array(3)
0: {date: "2019-02-03", deliveryStatus: false, endingDay: false, startingDay: true}
1: {date: "2019-02-04", deliveryStatus: false, endingDay: false, startingDay: true}
2: {date: "2019-02-05", deliveryStatus: false, endingDay: false, startingDay: false}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And, then from this, i am setting the states as above code. But, my state value is only being the last value of the array. And here is my initial state,

```
state = {finalPlanStatus: null, dates: [], deliveryStatus: [], startingDay: "", endingDay: []}
```

Comment: Your `setState` overwrite previous one every time

Comment: another questino - when you put your console.logs? please show full code of component

Comment: My initial state is an empty array, whats there to override ? And i am console logging on a onPress handler to check the state . onPressDateHandler() {
    console.log(this.state.dates);
  }

Comment: Oh your saying that,as its three array elemts . it overrides each elements ? Got it, how to tackle this and store each value as a array in state ? @VasiliyVanchuk

Comment: Please, show full component code. And are you sure, that your `onPress` handler called after `this.props.fetchPlanStatus` finished it's work?

Comment: While updating array in the `state` you can do like, `this.setState((prevState) => ({ dates: [...prevState.dates, element.date ], ... }))`

Comment: yes, brother ! Actually i am using a wix calendar. My aim is to show marked dates from the dates from the api. So, in the calendar there is an onpress handler to for each date. When using that function, i am tried with console log to check the state value., Wait let me post the code @VasiliyVanchuk

Comment: It works, perfectly but is there a way to set the state as object ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
componentWillMount() {

  const { phone, orderNo } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  this.props.fetchPlanStatus({phone, orderNo}, (snapShotValue) => {
      const fetchedPlans = snapShotValue;
      const dates = fetchedPlans.orderValidity[0].deliveryDates.map(element => element.date)
      this.setState((prevState) => { return { dates: [...prevState.dates, ...dates], finalPlanStatus: fetchedPlans } })
  });
  }
```